# Get tweet JSON into SQL table with nodejs

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, twitter

I'm getting some tweets from the twitter API with nodejs and saving some of the data with mysql. Gradually as I require more and more data from each tweet, it's become obvious I should just save the whole tweet each time. I'm looking for the cleanest way to save a whole tweet straight from a JSON object to a new row in my db.

I was surprised there aren't more node modules or anything pre-written for creating the database table ready for tweets and mapping a tweet's JSON schema directly to it - can anyone help? At the moment I'm using the 'mysql' module for queries and thought about combining it with 'json-sql' for building the query, but it seems like this must be such a common thing that there should be an even simpler way.

Is anyone aware of another process? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a document database? Or is sql a prerequisite for your project?

Comment: @Joel-Gregory good idea but it needs to be mysql for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually moved over to using MongoDB, it works really well with NodeJS and I'm really enjoying it.